# What are "Parforce Horns" and "Fürst Pless Horns"?

Tags: instruments, brass

I suddenly found on Thomann these types of horns: [*Parforce horn*](https://www.thomann.de/gb/parforce_horns.html) and [*Fürst Pless Horn*](https://www.thomann.de/gb/fuerst_pless_horns.html).

I searched for them on Wikipedia and similar sites, Google, etc., but all I find is in German or other languages. They are called like that in every country version of Thomann.

Since I could not find any information about these instruments, what are these instruments, what are they used for, how to play, what are they made of, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parforce horn is a hunting horn in the German tradition.  A brass instrument, a simplified French Horn.

Google will translate German information on the Internet into English.

[Parforce Horn](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parforcehorn&prev=search)

"Parforce horns are primarily used in hunting for blowing hunting signals . The large curl allows you to put your head and arm through and carry the horn over your shoulder. This leaves both hands free for riding."

Fürst Pless Horn is a smaller type of hunting horn.

Again, Google Translate is your friend.

[Furst Press Horn](https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&tab=wT&authuser=0&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fde.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FF%25C3%25BCrst-Pless-Horn)

"The Fürst-Pless-Horn is still used as a signaling instrument for blowing certain hunting horn signals, the so-called hunting control signals, in company hunts. In addition, the instrument is also used in hunting customs and in concert in so-called brass corps, e.g. B. at Hubertus fairs , also with Parforce horns in B , are used."

Comment: That  'horns in B' would be Bb for the rest of us, I suppose.

Comment: +1!  I had also said the 2 terms are easy to find with google in german wiki and readable with:  Google translator. But how could you poste the translatet links?

Comment: I don't usually relly on google translation. At least when translating to my language it usually sucks.

Comment: However, in this case, the result was useful - yes?

Comment: @Tim May I'm guessing that you already knew this, but for all others, in German 'B' is used for B flat and 'H' for B natural.